# код зацикливаеться после if what == "нет": если не поставить break, но хотелось бы понимать почему и как сделать это иначе

Tags: python, циклы, калькулятор

код зацикливаеться если после if what == "нет":  не поставить break, но хотелось бы понимать почему и как сделать это иначе, что бы после ввода "нет" цикл останавливался, в связи со значением i == False

```
def calculytor():
    what = input("Что делаем? (+,-):")
    a = float(input("Введи первое число:"))
    b = float(input("Введи второе число:"))
    if what == "+":
       c = a + b
       print("Результат: " + str(c) )
    elif what == "-":
       c = a - b
       print("Результат: " + str(c) )
    else:
        print("Неверная команда")

i = True
while i:
    calculytor()
    what = input("Ещё раз? да/нет ")

    if what == "нет":
        i == False
    else:
        i == True
```

Comment: Сори, но `calculytor`, выглядит смешно, лучше Вам использовать `calculator`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этом

```
i == False
```

Двойной знак равно это проверка равенства. То есть если what равно "нет" вы проверяете равно ли i False. Исправьте на

```
i = False
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

`i == False` - булевое выражение, то же, что написать `1 + 1`, значение никакой переменной от такого не поменяется

`i = False` - присваивание переменной новое значение, тогда в переменную сохранится другое значение, которое заметит `while i`